# Taking into account courses from another university

Tags: computer-science, international-students

I think about starting studies towards Master Degree in Computer Science abroad, I finished my bachelor studies few years ago, but I didn't stop studying, during these years I finished few courses of master degree in the domestic university, as result I have transcripts for all of them in English.

The question is what is is the common practice is there any chance that abroad university will consider credit on the courses I already finished, the point is if it's possible I want to lower the pressure to get credit on courses and mostly investing my time in research.

I checked this issue with few another universities in  my country, all of them taking into account the credit I already have with promise to give exemption from studying theses courses if there are requirement of the master degree and to give a credit for all of them.

Comment: Each university has different policies, and you should check with individual schools to see if your credit will transfer.  I know the program I graduated from would only allow up to two courses to transfer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best answer to this question is Chris Gregg's comment.

**You need to check with each individual school or even each individual program.**

The schools you already checked with will allow it. Chris's program allowed a maximum of two courses. My graduate program accepted transfer credits infrequently. Some programs may not accept any.

Comment: Yes, and it's important to check pretty carefully, since some departmental policies sound much more flexible on paper than they actually are.  For example, the policy may say "we'll award transfer credit if we decide the course is equivalent to our course", without making it clear that they almost never think anyone else's course is similar enough to count as equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Another factor to consider is how long ago you took those other courses. Some schools are more likely to accept recently-taken courses, but might balk on courses taken, say, over a decade ago.

Also, some schools will want to see an official course description before accepting the transfer credits (or, before letting you use those credits in place of requisite courses in their programs).